# php xml serialize and unserialize with pear

Tags: php, xml, serialization, xml-serialization, pear

I have noticed PEAR `XML_Serializer` and `XML_Unserializer` are not "reversible", for example :

```
<?php
$a = array(1, 2);
$serializer = new XML_Serializer();
$serializer->serialize($a);
$b = $serializer->getSerializedData(); 
print($b); // "<array><XML_Serializer_Tag>1</Xml_Serializer_Tag><XML_Serializer_Tag>2</Xml_Serializer_Tag></array>"
$unserializer = new XML_Unserializer(); 
$unserializer->unserialize($b);
$c = $unserializer->getUnserializedData();
print_r($c); // array('XML_Serializer_Tag' => array(1, 2)) instead of array(1, 2)
```

Are there any options for `XML_Unserializer` to remove `Xml_Serializer_Tag` recursively ?

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer in [XML_Unserializer options PEAR Documentation](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.xml.xml-serializer.xml-unserializer.options.php)

I modified a line in my code above and it worked :

```
$unserializer = new XML_Unserializer(array(XML_UNSERIALIZER_OPTION_IGNORE_KEYS => array('XML_Serializer_Tag')));
```

Too bad this is not the default value...

Comment: Would you consider filing a bug report at https://pear.php.net/bugs/report.php?package=XML_Serializer requesting the default value be changed? ;)